# Show that $\lambda_{2}(zz^\ast)=\lambda_{n-1}(zz^\ast)=0$.

Tags: matrices, hermitian-matrices

Show that $\lambda_{2}(zz^\ast)=\lambda_{n-1}(zz^\ast)=0$ where $z\in \mathbf{C}^n$ and $n\geq 2$.

I know that $zz^\ast$ is a Hermitian matrix, and all the eigenvalues are nonnegative, but how to prove that $zz^\ast$ has only one positive eigenvalue (which is $z^\ast z$) ?

Comment: Hint: what is the rank of $zz^*$?

Comment: Let $x\in \mathbf{C}^n$, $zz^\ast x=\langle z,x\rangle z$, which means $zz^\ast$ maps $\mathbf{C}^n$ into the vector $z$, so rank$ zz^\ast=1$. This implies  $zz^\ast$ has only one nonzero eigenvalue. Is this right?

Comment: @Charmbracelet Yes, that's right.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you!